# Stack Overflow Business language dialog

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-business

There seems to be a problem with the "Update your language preference" dialog on *stackoverflowbusiness.com*. When you close the dialog by clicking x, the page gets reset to the stored language preference instead of staying on the current page.

How to reproduce:

Go to https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/uk/talent. Then open https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/de/talent (German version). Now a "Update your language preference" dialog pops up.

[image: Pop-up dialog]

As one can see, the desired language (German) is already selected and the page in the background is also in German. But, when you now close the dialog by clicking the x-button, the page reloads and shows the UK page.

I would expect from a page that shows a dialog that only the dialog gets closed when clicking the x-button. Especially when then desired language is already selected.

Edit:
I tested it under Windows 10, Chrome and Edge and on Android Chrome.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 58.0.2